# How to access the values of a dictionary that is nested inside a dictionary

Tags: python

I need to write a function that takes a dictionary with its keys equal to a name and the values are dictionaries. The dictionary that is nested inside has the key equal to a task and its value equal to the number of hours that task takes. I need to return a dictionary with the task as the key and its value a dictionary with the name as the key and its value the hours.

I can't figure out how to access the values inside the nested dictionary so the values in the nested dictionary are just the same as the keys. 
Here is what I have:

```
def sprintLog(sprnt):
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict = {x: {y: y for y in sprnt.keys() if x in sprnt[y]} for l in sprnt.values() for x in l}
    return new_dict
```

If I pass in a dictionary such as:

```
d = {'Ben': {'task1': 5}, 'alex': {'task1': 10, 'task2': 4}}
```

I'm expecting to get a dictionary such as:

```
new_dict = {'task1': {'Ben': 5, 'alex': 10}, 'task2': {'alex': 4}}
```

But what I am getting at the moment is:

```
new_dict = {'task1': {'Ben': 'Ben', 'alex': 'alex'}, 'task2': {'alex': 'alex'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is work for me

```
def sprintLog(sprnt):
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict = {x: {y: sprnt[y][x] for y in sprnt.keys() if x in sprnt[y]} for l in sprnt.values() for x in l}
    return new_dict

print(sprintLog({'Ben': {'task1': 5}, 'alex': {'task1': 10, 'task2': 4}}))
```

Comment: you don't need the `new_dict = {}` in the first line of the function :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the above answers with list comprehension are correct, I'll just slide this one for better understanding :)

```
from collections import defaultdict

def sprintLog(sprnt): # d = {'Ben': {'task1': 5}, 'alex': {'task1': 10, 'task2': 4}}
    new_dict = defaultdict(dict)

    for parent in sprnt.keys():
        for sub_parent in sprnt[parent].keys():
           new_dict[sub_parent][parent] = sprnt[parent][sub_parent]

    return new_dict

a = sprintLog({'Ben': {'task1': 5}, 'alex': {'task1': 10, 'task2': 4}})

print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you're looking for:

```
d = {'Ben': {'task1': 5}, 'alex': {'task1': 10, 'task2': 4}}


def sprintLog(sprnt):
    return {x: {y: f[x] for y,f in sprnt.items() if x in sprnt[y]} for l in sprnt.values() for x in l}


print(sprintLog(d))
```

You need to use `sprnt.items()` instead of `sprnt.keys()` so to get the values too.